# MSAccess - SQL query everything to the right OR left of a character

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2016

Using Ms Access 2016 I'm trying to run a SELECT query to match strings on a column from table1 and table2. I can do this with the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
WHERE a.luCode LIKE b.Code
```

table1.luCode only eve rhas one code, however, table2.Code sometimes has two codes in it separated by ";":

```
table2.Code
--------------------
someCode1
someCode2
someCode3;someCode4
someCode5
```

How can I perform the above query checking both to the left and right of the ";"?

So far I've been trying to use InStr (just to the left) using:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
WHERE a.luCode LIKE LEFT(b.Code,(InStr(1,b.Code,";"))-1);
```

But I get a datatype mismatch.
Figuring this would be either "null" values of empty strings (after checking it seems it's empty strings) I can add an IIF statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
WHERE IIF(b.Code<>"",a.luCode LIKE LEFT(b.Code,(InStr(1,b.Code,";"))-1));
```

This throws an "invalid procedure call" error.

I could just make a new column with the data after the ";" but there must be a way to do this with InStr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a really, really bad data format.  You should have a table with one row for each code, instead of throwing them together in a string.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  In this case, you can try:

```
WHERE ';' & b.luCode & ';' LIKE '*;' & a.Code & ';*'
```

Or alternatively use `instr()` with the same logic.

Comment: Agreed this is a very bad idea. The above is only returning records that don't contain ";" (i.e. only have one code in b.Code)

Comment: @OliverBurdekin . . . The table aliases were backwards.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Gordon. That's working now. I'm also looking into how to best solve this horrible data format.